# How to I get Access 2010 to creating an Error Table if message "Microsoft Access was unable to append all data...."

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a vba that imports data from excel into a Access 2010 table. The problem is the Access table has some field validations which is the reason for the error message. I'm okay with the errors, but I want row with errors to be pasted into an error table. Also, the excel data isn't from me, so I cannot validate the data before I import. I want to send the "error table" to the person who sent it to me to correct the data. This is my import vba that I found and works.

```
Public Function GetMyFile() As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
Dim fdFilePick As FileDialog
Dim varSelectedFile As Variant
Dim strInFile As String
Dim strImport70 As String
Set fdFilePick = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
DoCmd.Hourglass True
    With fdFilePick
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "&Import"
        .InitialFileName = Application.CurrentProject.Path
        .Filters.Add "Excel", "*.xlsx"
            If .Show Then
                For Each varSelectedFile In .SelectedItems
                    strInFile = CStr(varSelectedFile)
                    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, strImport70
                    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Import70", strInFile, True
                Next
            Else
                MsgBox "Import Process Canceled", vbCritical, "Import Canceled"
                GetMyFile = False
                Exit Function
            End If
    End With
End Function
```

If none of this makes sense, please ask. I just feel there has to be a way to capture the row with errors.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using VBA to import data, Access isn't going to put the rows with errors into a `Paste Errors` table like it does if you copy/paste the data into a table.

What you can do is create a copy of your table as a TempImport table and remove all constraints (validation) that would prevent rows from being imported.  Then import the Excel data into this TempImport table.  Now use code and/or queries to validate the data in TempImport.  If all rows are good, append them from your TempImport table to your final table.  If any rows are bad, export them to your desired format to send back and then discard everything in TempImport.

Comment: I see, now I understand why I can't find a vba solution. Can I create a vba or does it have to be in sql to validate fields in a query? The the two tables have either 14 and 24 columns which need to be validated.  Also, thank you Jericho for answering my question.

Comment: To validate the rows in TempImport, you would use a combination of queries called by VBA code.  You did not give any specifics about the validation rules, but for example, if ColumnA requires a value, you would `SELECT * FROM TempImport WHERE ColumnA Is Null` which would get all rows where ColumnA is invalid and therefore you want to send back.

Comment: Thank you Jericho! To answer your question about validation rules, each column is Field Size driven but some may be Field Size plus text (e.g. 02; Field size 2 and text 01, 02 etc...). If that makes sense. The data I get from the field may have more than 2 field size with characters not listed in the list (e.g. 099). There are multiple variations of validation within a table.

Comment: I tried to upvote your answer, but it doesn't do anything. I've hit the up arrow numerous time, but nothing happens.

Comment: Turns out you can't upvote until you have a reputation of at least 15.  Below 15, you can only post questions and accept answers to your questions.

Comment: Though, I think you deserve credit for at least trying to help me, makes sense why I couldn't upvote. I accepted your answer for you to get credit. Thanks again.